# Blackberry facebook Dropdown Menu

Tags: facebook, blackberry

I was finding around the website but i cannot get the source. The menu was semi-transparent which got `news feed`, `profile` and etc.

I need the sample that creating something like transparent screen on top of current screen. Someone can link me to there?

Comment: Could u please explain your problem some what clear.

Comment: I had edited the content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following links would helps u a lot...

[Transparent Popup screen in Blackberry](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Transparent-Popup-screen-in-Blackberry/td-p/1737717)

[Transparent screen...again!?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Transparent-screen-again/td-p/389032)

[Creating a transparent screen](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Creating-a-transparent-screen/td-p/396420)

[How to set popup screen transparent...?](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-set-popup-screen-transparent/td-p/1381583)

[want to get the home screen api called](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/want-to-get-the-home-screen-api-called/td-p/559376/page/2)